# How to properly setup DocuSIgn oAuth2 process

Tags: docusignapi

I'm really confused about the `OAuth2` process of your API.On the docs it says "The client application should show a `UI` to prompt the user for email/password and is responsible to keep the information confidential and not store it locally."

My point is the purpose of `OAuth2` is not fulfilled here. Client Application should have no concern with the user's email and password. DocuSign says don't store the password locally! What If any client develops an application that stores the users' passwords and create security threats for DocuSign users?

I have worked with several API's using `OAuth2` authentication, this is my first time to encounter a different flow. Could you please enlighten me on how to actually apply this, can you give me examples?

Here's how our applications works. It connects docusigns users, we will hold their access_tokens and we will use it to send custom envelopes/widgets on their behalf. We don't want to ask the users email and password using our domain.

I don't think I'm on the right track, I'm kinda confuse please I need your assistance.

Answer (score 1):

The key issue is that the current [DocuSign REST API OAuth2](https://www.docusign.com/p/RESTAPIGuide/RESTAPIGuide.htm#OAuth2/OAuth2%20Authentication%20Support%20in%20DocuSign%20REST%20API.htm) feature does **not** support Single Sign On.

Rather, the OAuth2 feature enables your DocuSign Client app to not store a clear user name/pw pair for authenticating with the API on behalf of a named user.

On the other hand, "Send on Behalf of Others" (SOBO) also enables an app to not store the user name/pw of other people who will be sending out transactions (envelopes). Instead you designate one user name as the "Authenticating User". [More info.](https://www.docusign.com/p/RESTAPIGuide/RESTAPIGuide.htm#OAuth2/Acting%20As%20Other%20Account%20Users.htm)

So it all depends on your use case. Remember that the API is most often used to send transactions out for signing, not to sign documents. You can send as a "system user" or you can send on behalf of other users within your account.

To remove the need for your client app to store a user name/pw, your app can:

1. Request a user name/pw from a human
2. [Obtain an OAuth2 token.](https://www.docusign.com/p/RESTAPIGuide/RESTAPIGuide.htm#OAuth2/OAuth2%20Token%20Request.htm)
3. Forget the user name/pw
4. Use the token instead of the user name/pw pair in subsequent API calls. The token doesn't expire, so it can be stored and used without limit. (It can be explicitly revoked by the user either through the DocuSign web interface or via the API.)

For your use case:

> Here's how our application works. It connects DocuSigns users, we will hold their access_tokens and we will use it to send custom envelopes/widgets on their behalf. We don't want to ask the users email and password using our domain.

It sounds like your app should have one "Authenticating User" per account that the end users belong to. (You don't say whether all of your users are in the same account or not.) Typically, each company/customer of DocuSign has one account for all of their users. But many DocuSign customers do have multiple accounts for various reasons. An individual user can belong to multiple accounts.

The Authenticating User will Send on Behalf of (SOBO) the end users. In this scenario, you do not need to know the pw of the users. (And you will not be holding their OAuth2 tokens nor will you need to request their pw.)

But you do need their email (their user name within DocuSign). Presumably your app has this information.

In addition, you need to decide how the Sending User accounts will be provisioned within DocuSign. You can assume that the account exists and then gracefully handle the case when it doesn't.

Or you can provision the user within the account via the API. [Create_user method.](https://www.docusign.com/p/RESTAPIGuide/RESTAPIGuide.htm#REST%20API%20References/Add%20User%20to%20Account.htm)

Also, will the users be logging into DocuSign directly? If so, then the users may want to implement SSO with DocuSign. DocuSign SSO uses SAML.

**Added**

If you use the Authenticating User idea with SOBO, then think of the Authenticating User as the system user for your app (but you need one per DocuSign account). Credentials for the system user are often included in a config file and you can still do that. Or you can create the token for the system user at time of install--the name/pw would be added by an admin. There is no need to ask an ordinary user for her password.

For an app that is of use to any DocuSign *sender*, in any account, typically you'd have a provisioning step of "adding" the app to the new account. This would be an administrative step, done by the admin. Your sw would instruct the admin for the new account to create an Authenticating User and then enter that user's email/pw.

If your app just sends signing requests (or even just message received confirmation requests) from your app to any random person associated with your app, remember that signing is free--the recipient users don't need an account on DocuSign.

If your clients want to "send" signing requests (via your app) and see them in their accounts, etc, then it sounds like you want to use SOBO with an Authenticated User for each of your clients' provisioned accounts. Note the [**first paragraph** in this doc](https://www.docusign.com/p/RESTAPIGuide/RESTAPIGuide.htm#OAuth2/Acting%20As%20Other%20Account%20Users.htm).

**Not using SOBO** You can also plan your app as follows:

1. Joe user indicates to your app that he has a DocuSign account and wants your app to send on his behalf.
2. You look in your token store. If you have a token for Joe, you use it. If you don't, then you tell Joe that he must provision your app to work with his DocuSign account. To do that, you need him to enter his DS email/pw one time.
3. You use the Joe's stored token to send the signing request *as* Joe.

You're right that a trust question may arise with this flow. To minimize how often you need to ask for a DocuSign email/pw, I'd go with the Authenticating User + SOBO. That way you'd only have to ask once when a DocuSign account is added to your system.

**Added some more**
If your clients, with respect to their DocuSign accounts are *sparse* (in other words, your clients usually don't have DocuSign accounts in common), then I would go with the simpler non-SOBO flow.

Why? Simpler for your customers. If they will be the only person in their DocuSign account to use your app, then there is little point in going through a provisioning step at the account level.

You're right that some of your clients may ask, "why aren't you using OAuth2?" The answer is that the DocuSign API doesn't yet support it.

**Final addition**

DocuSign support for OAuth2 in the DocuSign REST API: As the [docs](https://www.docusign.com/p/RESTAPIGuide/Content/OAuth2/OAuth2%20Authentication%20Support%20in%20DocuSign%20REST%20API.htm) say:

> The Resource Owner Password Grant is the only OAuth2 flow supported in the DocuSign REST API. This allows a client application to obtain an access token directly from the REST API by presenting the user name, password and integrator key for the user. After an access token is obtained, it is then used in API calls instead of the user name/password/integrator key combination.

For information on SOBO, see [docs 1,](https://www.docusign.com/developer-center/explore/features/sobo) [docs 2](https://www.docusign.com/p/APIGuide/Content/Introduction+Changes/Send%20On%20Behalf%20Of%20Functionality.htm), and [docs 3](https://10226ec94e53f4ca538f-0035e62ac0d194a46695a3b225d72cc8.ssl.cf2.rackcdn.com/send-on-behalf-of-functionality-guide.pdf). If you have further questions on SOBO, please open a new StackOverflow question.

Comment: Thank you for that wonderful answer. But still I'm not convinced on the flow you gave about getting a token. Any devs could do the same way, yes, they can store the user's email/password without them knowing even it was stated so. I hope you got my point here. As a DocuSign NORMAL user, if I knew this flow from the start I would not rather login to any application because its too risky right? there is no guarantee that this application will not store my sensitive credentials.

Comment: Yes, I only have one application. The users of the app are not in the same account. The application welcomes any DocuSign users, who wants to send transactions to their users. For example. I have a documents to be send out for signing ( for several users ). Instead of doing this manually(myself). I'm gonna use the app to do it automatically. Is SOBO the right solution for this? Do you have any examples on that? I'm looking forward for your answer. Thanks

Comment: "The answer is that the DocuSign API doesn't yet support it." really? Then why did you gave me oAuth2 links and guides if the API doesn't support it in the first place? Are you a developer of the API or something? I'm not sure if you know what you're talking about and if its true or maybe you need to provide me more clarification to this matter. I appreciate the help anyway. But it would be more understandable if you give me a real example instead specially on the SOBO part.